# How to add firebase library into Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I want add below libraries into my application :

I want add below libraries into my application :

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.0.0'
```

but when sync app show me below error : https://image.ibb.co/e7vzja/rfggtr.png

**My gradle.build file :**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
//apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-crash'

buildscript {
    repositories {
//      maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

//  dependencies {
//      classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
//  }
}

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ir.kindnesswall"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("key.jks")
            storePassword ""
            keyAlias ""
            keyPassword ""
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}

// run ./gradlew :app:firebaseUploadReleaseProguardMapping from project directory that has gradlew.bat
setProperty("FirebaseServiceAccountFilePath", rootProject.rootDir.absolutePath + FirebaseServiceAccountFilePath)

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'

    compile('com.github.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.5.6@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }

//  compile('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:5.0.8@aar') {
//      transitive = true
//  }
    compile 'com.github.traex.rippleeffect:library:1.3'

    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'

    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'

    compile 'com.github.rey5137:material:1.2.1'

    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'

//  compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'

//  compile 'com.roughike:bottom-bar:1.4.0.1'

    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.3.1'


    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.0'
//  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.6'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.0.0'

    compile 'com.github.Aspsine:MultiThreadDownload:920fd6f670'

    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

    compile 'com.heinrichreimersoftware:material-intro:1.6.2'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

How to fix this error?

Comment: Have you added this line    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0' in  your root-level build.gradle file

Comment: @NarenderReddy, I added this but not worked

Comment: didi you google json file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.0.1'
```

try using these version.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Android Studio 2.2 or later than you can follow assistance provided in android studio for that go to tools and than select firebase and than its product and it will assist you with all information. For more information refer this [Link](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/firebase.html)

Answer (score 0):

First you have to add Google play services and Google repository in android SDK, Then add this `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'` in build.gradle (project)