# Failed to resolve firebase-database-15.0.0

Tags: java, android-studio

I'm currently getting an error on android studio: http://prntscr.com/lebil3

I'm obviously a noob. It has something to do with Firebase, which I connected to my app with some errors, but it did connect successfully.

Comment: use this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45157716/how-to-add-firebase-library-into-android-studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the link you had given and your implementation looks like this:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1:15.0.0'
```

I think the problem is the last 15.0.0 part. That should not be there. It should be just 16.0.1. 
Also try adding this to your app build.gradle:

```
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
```

If this doesn't work, in your project level build.gradle file, check if you have:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
```

and the plugin at the bottom of your app level build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

If none of this has worked, check out [this documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) by Firebase on adding Firebase to your Android app.
Hope this helps!

Comment: You are correct, 15.0.0 was the problem, all I needed to do is to delete it. Worked like charm. Thank You so much !

Comment: Please mark this answer as useful if it helped you. You're welcome for the help!

Comment: I still have some warnings though and about libraries. I added the suggestions from android studio but the error still occurs. PICTURE: http://prntscr.com/lec028

Comment: Yes it is because you are still missing the plugins I mentioned in my answer. The "apply plugin: 'com.google......" should be at the bottom of your file. Also, if you read the error, it says you must have "firebase-core" which I mentioned in my answer above as well. The firebase-core implementation should go in with the firebase-database. If you are having trouble even after adding everything I have said, check the link for Firebase documentation. Hope it helps and if it does, don't forget to accept it as an answer!

Comment: Thank you so much Elvis! I am glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 1):

Please add google() on Project Bluild

allprojects {
    repositories {

```
    google()

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Change `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1:15.0.0'` to 
`implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4'`. I had the exact same [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53128350/adding-firebase-dependency-causes-gradle-sync-to-fail) a few days back. If that still does not work, compare your other dependencies with mine and adjust accordingly.

Comment: Yeah, this was the problem. Thank You !

Comment: @Elvis no problem, don't forget to accept this as an answer by clicking on the tick, a vote up would be nice too ;)

Comment: I still have some warnings though and about libraries. I added the suggestions from android studio but the error still occurs. PICTURE: prntscr.com/lec028

Comment: @Elvis mirror your module/project gradle files which you have to mine: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53128350/adding-firebase-dependency-causes-gradle-sync-to-fail, I think the problem may be that there are version conflicts, best to use all the updated versions like I did.